Querying Smartsheet Rows with Specific Column Values
I want to use smart sheet API to read sheet data. my sheet has end Date column. I want to fetch rows which are greater than certain date. is there any way to do this using smart sheet API
I tried to Read each cell Value, but i couldn't do this date filter.

Welcome to stackoverflow! You mentioned "but i couldn't do this date filter" - can you edit your post and include some more details what exactly you tried?
